# Simplify an irrational decimal to its simple fraction equivalent using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, fractions

Here is my problem:

I am writing a program to solve a statistical problem from timed coding challenge using Python 2.7
I'm not allowed to use many external packages ( however I can use Fractions). To finish my problem I need to convert an irrational decimal number to it's fraction equivalent.

**Example Input:**

```
0.6428571428571428 [i.e. 9/14]
```

**Problem:**

I want to output `9/14` in this instance but if I do something like:

```
print(Fraction(0.6428571428571428))
```

It will print some ungodly long fraction that can't be reduced.

Is there a way to reduce `0.6428571428571428` to `9/14` **without forcing** Fraction to round closest to `14` (since I need to use it for a lot of different fractions)?

**Another Example:**

```
.33333333333 (i.e. 1/3)
```

**Current Output:**

```
print(Fraction(.333333333333333)) # Outputs 6004799503160061/18014398509481984
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know around how large your denominators get, you can use `limit_denominator`. See the docs [for this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator)

Here's what you'd get setting 100000 as your denominator

```
from fractions import Fraction
print(Fraction(.333333333333333).limit_denominator(max_denominator=100000))
# 1/3

print(Fraction(0.6428571428571428).limit_denominator(max_denominator=100000))
# 9/14
```

We're giving plenty of freedom with `100000` as the upper limit but it still finds the result we are looking for. You can adjust that number to suit your needs.

For these cases, I continued to get these results up to `10**14` and I start getting different results at `10**15` which is because, as  Olivier Melançon points, that we have 15 digits in our input and when using `max_denominator` the error is `1/(2 * max_denominator)`

Comment: I'd add a note regarding the fact that the error on the fraction representation is then 1/(2 * max_denominator)

Comment: I think this what I was looking for.  As long as they don't throw a curve ball test case at me.  Thank you.

Comment: It explains why you started getting a different fraction at 10**15. It's precisely because your input has 15 digits